# Pluck JavaScript object items into separate arrays

Tags: javascript

I need to take an array of objects like this...

```
var users = [{
    id: 0,
    full_name: 'None',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
},
{
    id: 1,
    full_name: 'Jason Davis',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
},
{
    id: 2,
    full_name: 'Eric',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
}];
```

and build these 3 arrays from the objects above.  The array key number should match on all.  So array with full_name = Jason Davis should match array key 1 on the ID array

THe idea is I should be able to rebuild the objects above by doing this...

```
id[1]
full_name[1]  
gravatar_url[1]
```

these above should all map to the object with user Jason Davis.

```
var id = [0, 1, 2];

var full_name = [
     'None',
     'Jason Davis',
     'Eric'
];

var gravatar_url = [
    'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80',
    'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80',
    'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
];
```

**The Reasoning**

I am building this using a popover  selector library...

[image]

The library only accepts a single array of data which is shown as each item.  In this image it is the user name.

(to clarify, the image above I added the thumbnail images into the DOM manually, the library does not accept a 2nd data on each item yet)

By doing what my question ask, I can assign the user image to another array

The library builds the items HTML like this...

```
        for (var i in this.options.items) {
            var itemElement = $(this.options.templates.pickerItem);
            itemElement.find('i').html(this.options.items[i]);
            itemElement.data('pickerValue', this.options.items[i])
                    .on('click.picker', itemClickFn);
            this.picker.find('.picker-items').append(itemElement);
        }
```

It calls `this.options.items[i]` to get the name.  If I have my own 2nd array of images I can use the key to show the correct user image with its name!

Comment: What problem are you having? Just loop through the original array, and push each property onto the corresponding array.

Comment: E.g. `id.push(users[i].id);`

Comment: Please update the question with your attempted solution, so we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way of doing things.

The process is-

Read the array, store the data into specific arrays as needed. Access them using index.

```
var users = [{
    id: 0,
    full_name: 'None',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
},
{
    id: 1,
    full_name: 'Jason Davis',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
},
{
    id: 2,
    full_name: 'Eric',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
}];

var id_arr=[];
var name_arr=[];
var gravatar_url_arr=[];

for (var i=0; i<users.length;i++)
{
  id_arr[i] = users[i].id;
  name_arr[i] = users[i].full_name;
  gravatar_url_arr[i] = users[i].gravatar_url;
}

//Displaying all arrays
console.log(id_arr);
console.log(name_arr);
console.log(gravatar_url_arr);

//Get's the result what you need
console.log(id_arr[1]);
console.log(name_arr[1]);
console.log(gravatar_url_arr[1]);
```

**Demo - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozzmob/5Lwrwpnb/)**

Comment: [why is using for-in with array iteration a bad idea?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1)

Comment: @Barmar Updated the optimal code. Thanks for the info. I didn't know that. Added a JSFiddle link as well for more clarity demo.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to loop over your array and insert each property into an appropriate array:

```
var id = [], full_name = [], gravatar_url = [];
for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var u = users[i];                 
    id.push(u.id);
    full_name.push(u.full_name);
    gravatar_url.push(u.gravatar_url);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this

Try like this

```
var id=users.map(function(x){ return x.id; });
console.log(id);
var full_name=users.map(function(x){ return x.full_name; });
console.log(full_name);
var gravatar_url=users.map(function(x){ return x.gravatar_url; });
console.log(gravatar_url);
```

**Snippet**

```js
var users = [{
    id: 0,
    full_name: 'None',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
},
{
    id: 1,
    full_name: 'Jason Davis',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
},
{
    id: 2,
    full_name: 'Eric',
    gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
}];

var id=users.map(function(x){ return x.id; });
console.log(id);
var full_name=users.map(function(x){ return x.full_name; });
console.log(full_name);
var gravatar_url=users.map(function(x){ return x.gravatar_url; });
console.log(gravatar_url);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map functionality here.

```
var names = users.map(function(item) {
    return item['full_name'];
});
```

Now the names is the array of full_names as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `for` loop , `while` loop , `Object.keys()`

```
var len = users.length, max = len * len, res = [];
for (var i = 0, j = len; i < max; i++) {
   if (!res[i % j]) {
     res[i % j] = Array();
     var k = 0;
     while (k < len) {
       res[i % j][k] = users[k][Object.keys(users[i % j])[i % j]];
       ++k;
     } 
   } 
}

var id = res[0], full_name = res[1], gravatar = res[2];
```

```js
var users = [{
  id: 0,
  full_name: 'None',
  gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
}, {
  id: 1,
  full_name: 'Jason Davis',
  gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
}, {
  id: 2,
  full_name: 'Eric',
  gravatar_url: 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/31b64e4876d603ce78e04102c67d6144?s=80'
}];

var len = users.length, max = len * len, res = [];
for (var i = 0, j = len; i < max; i++) {
   if (!res[i % j]) {
     res[i % j] = Array();
     var k = 0;
     while (k < len) {
       res[i % j][k] = users[k][Object.keys(users[i % j])[i % j]];
       ++k;
     } 
   } 
}

var id = res[0], full_name = res[1], gravatar = res[2];

console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2)
            ,"\n\n", id[1], full_name[1], gravatar[1])
```